# How can I print the current location on my console using geoLocator package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, location, emulation

Here is my code in a loading_screen.dart file. I've clearly mentioned to print my position and even called the method in onpressed. Still no response from it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

    void getLocation() async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run it on iOS simulator?

Comment: No, on android emulator. Actually the emulator itself was causing a minor problem. But I fixed it by deleting and making a new one :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps missing from your implementation.

First you need to check for permission, if permission is allowed, get location else ask for permission.

You also need to add permission in you manifest for android and in info.plist for ios

sample code :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _Test createState() => _Test();
}

class _Test extends State<Test>{

  void getLocation() async{
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if(permission == LocationPermission.always || permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
      printLocation();
    }else{
      requestPermission();
    }
  }

  requestPermission() async{
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if(permission == LocationPermission.always || permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
      printLocation();
    }else{
      requestPermission();
    }
  }

  printLocation() async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low, timeLimit: Duration(seconds: 10));
    print(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```